# How to insert HTML using foreach() without echo

Tags: php, html

I have this working code in my view:

```
<?php
                $task_num = 0;
                foreach ($curent_day->getTasksList() as $task){

                    echo '<div class="task">';
                        echo '<span class="task_id">'.($task_num+1).'.'.'</span>';
                        echo '<div class="task_time">';
                            echo '<span class="task_time_start">'.$task->getStartTime().'</span>';
                            echo '<span class="task_time_finish">'.$task->getFinishTime().'</span>';
                        echo '</div>';
                        echo '<a href="/" class="task_name">'.$task->name.'</a>';
                        echo '<a href="/" class="btn task_start btn_disabled">Start</a>';
                        echo '<a href="/" class="btn task_finish btn_disabled">Finish</a>';
                        echo '<div class="status_round '.$task->status.'"></div>';
                    echo '</div>';

                $task_num++;

                }
?>
```

Is there any way to get rid of 'echo'?
P.S. and is the way to insert HTML with HTML helper more correct even if it takes more space?

Comment: USE PHP shorthand. Example: <h1><?=$var ?></h1>

Comment: Use Inline PHP: 
Example: 
<?php foreach($array as $key => $value): ?>
<h1><?=$value ?></h1>
<?php endforeach ?>

Comment: this has nothing to do with yii2 tag is basic php question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can drop `echo` completely and use native HTML syntax:

```
<?php $task_num = 0 ?>
<?php foreach ($curent_day->getTasksList() as $task): ?>
    <div class='task'>
        <span class='task_id'><?= ++$task_num ?></span>
        <div class='task_time'>
            <span class='task_time_start'><?= $task->getStartTime() ?></span>
            <span class='task_time_finish'><?= $task->getFinishTime() ?></span>
        </div>
        <a href='/' class='task_name'><?= $task->name ?></a>
        <a href='/' class='btn task_start btn_disabled'>Start</a>
        <a href='/' class='btn task_finish btn_disabled'>Finish</a>
        <div class='status_round <?= $task->status ?>'></div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

This will give you better syntax highlighting and autoformatting support in your IDE/editor.

Answer (score 0):

There are several different ways that you can concatenate the string by using single quotes and double quotes, or by using a variable and the ".=" operator to append text onto the end of a string.  Just google php strings  & concatenation and it will have more than you need to figure this out.

But using you example here is a method:

```
$task_num = 0;
foreach ($curent_day->getTasksList() as $task){
echo 
'<div class="task">' .
  '<span class="task_id">' . ($task_num+1) . '.'.'</span>' .
    '<div class="task_time">' .
    '<span class="task_time_start">' . $task->getStartTime() . '</span>' .
    '<span class="task_time_finish">' . $task->getFinishTime() . '</span>' .
    '</div>' . 
  '<a href="/" class="task_name">'.$task->name.'</a>' . 
  '<a href="/" class="btn task_start btn_disabled">Start</a>' . 
  '<a href="/" class="btn task_finish btn_disabled">Finish</a>' . 
  '<div class="status_round '.$task->status.'"></div>' .
'</div>';

$task_num++;

}
```

You have to echo to output you data to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

> You need not use string concatenation or multiple echo statements.

**Alternative**

```
$task_num = 0;
  foreach ($curent_day->getTasksList() as $task){
    $task_num++;
    echo
      "<div class='task'>
        <span class='task_id'>{$task_num}</span>
          <div class='task_time'>
          <span class='task_time_start'>{$task->getStartTime()}</span>
          <span class='task_time_finish'>{$task->getFinishTime()}</span>
          </div>
        <a href='/' class='task_name'>{$task->name}</a>
        <a href='/' class='btn task_start btn_disabled'>Start</a>
        <a href='/' class='btn task_finish btn_disabled'>Finish</a>
        <div class='status_round {$task->status}'></div>
      </div>";

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate your html in one variable and then you can use it with one time echo statement

```
<?php
            $task_num = 0;
            $html = '';
            foreach ($curent_day->getTasksList() as $task){
                $html .= '<div class="task">';
                $html .= '<span class="task_id">'.($task_num+1).'.'.'</span>';
                $html .= '<div class="task_time">';
                $html .= '<span class="task_time_start">'.$task->getStartTime().'</span>';
                $html .= '<span class="task_time_finish">'.$task->getFinishTime().'</span>';
                 $html .= '</div>';
                 $html .= '<a href="/" class="task_name">'.$task->name.'</a>';
                 $html .=  '<a href="/" class="btn task_start btn_disabled">Start</a>';
                 $html .= '<a href="/" class="btn task_finish btn_disabled">Finish</a>';
                 $html .= '<div class="status_round '.$task->status.'"></div>';
                $html .=  '</div>';

            $task_num++;

            }?>
```